# How to query for certain text in log messages from Google App Engine that are exported to BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have used the 'Create Export' in the Logging section of Google Cloud Platform to export log entries into Big Query for analysis

[image]

Here is part of the structure of the table in BigQuery that logs the log entry

[image]

I want to search for entries that contains this user id 14994838999176.

In BigQuery, I issue the following query (in standard SQL dialect),

```
SELECT * FROM gae_log.appengine_googleapis_com_request_log_20180323

where protoPayload.line.logMessage  like '%14994838999176%'

LIMIT 1000
```

It failed with the error message:

```
 Query Failed

 Error: Cannot access field logMessage on a value with type 
 ARRAY<STRUCT<time TIMESTAMP, severity STRING, logMessage STRING, ...>> at [3:25]
```

How can I correct my sql statement?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why this query failed is because you have a table with nested repeated field **protoPayload.line** (datatype RECORD).

You can try [implicit unnesting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#syntax), it would be something like:

```
SELECT x
FROM `gae_log.appengine_googleapis_com_request_log_20180323` as t, 
      t.protoPayload.line AS x
WHERE x.logMessage  like '%14994838999176%'
```

You can also have a look on how to **query STRUCT elements in an ARRAY** [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#querying-struct-elements-in-an-array).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM gae_log.appengine_googleapis_com_request_log_20180323,  
     UNNEST(protoPayload.line) as line
where 
     line.logMessage  like '%14994838999176%'
LIMIT 1000
```

Basically, you need to use `UNNEST` to query an `ARRAY` in BigQuery.